# Terminal Persistence just doesn't work sometimes, named/colored terminals just go missing from one day to the next

Tags: terminal, persistence

This feature:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/advanced#_persistent-sessions

I think it is just the revive part that I care about.  I have 2 on-premises Exchange orgs and EXO to manage on the daily, and have 3 different colored/named PowerShell terminals which typically open automatically.  I haven't had to do anything to make this possible.

The last two times I can remember that, suddenly my terminals have just vanished between when I closed VS Code and now that I'm re-opening, there is an update available and I need to "Restart to update".  It's before I actually do that action, that I spot the problem.  So the update itself seems to just turf my stuff.  At that rate, why even bother asking me to restart to update.  Just tear the band-aid off.

Or, can we please fix this?  What can I do to help, as a user (non-developer) of VS Code?

I have not tried anything because I have no idea what I should or shouldn't mess with.  The documentation, settings names, etc., it's not crystal clear to me what they mean.  I am expecting this good feature to stay working more persistently.  I can understand the odd flub, but every update is pretty annoying.

Even just a tip on what I can be doing better to avoid this issue (if that's a possibility) would be great.